# CSS Shadows all four sides of div

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I want to achieve this in CSS - not CSS3 as I want it to be supported by all browsers
[image: bg with shadows on all sides]

ie a div containing content, with the shadows on every side. The top area will be used for navigation. I have searched for tutorials but so far to no avail. Help!

Comment: sad, but IE do not display shadows made with CSS. You need to create images as shadows (some gifs, IE6 do not display alpha channel of png files)

Comment: Is this a dynamic box... meaning will the width/height every change depending on content?

Comment: For Cross Browser Compatibility drop shadows using only CSS...check these links out <br/>
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/cross-browser-box-shadows/ <br/>
http://coolhomepages.com/How-to-make-easy-gradient-shadow-CSS-DIV-boxes/blog-48.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ventus said is not possible to use css shadows with ie (only ie9). But you can use [shadowOn](http://shadowon.codeplex.com/). It's a great jquery plugin and very easy in use. With it you will have cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 18):

Box Shadow works in all mordern [IE>8] browsers, This code uses no images and works in all browsers in IE versions below 9.

```
 box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
 -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
 -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;

  /* For IE<9 */  
  filter:
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=0,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=45,strength=2),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=90,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=135,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=180,strength=10),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=225,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=270,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9,direction=315,strength=2);
```

Box shadow supported from IE 9 onwards.

Comment: @certainlyakey Thanks for pointing out, i've updated styles to make it work in IE.

Comment: Only the last filter was applying for me. To get all sides to work for me in IE8, I had to remove the commas. According to the following article from MSDN, they are separated by a space, not a comma: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

[CSS3pie](http://css3pie.com) is a tool that lets you use some css3 properties in IE.

What you're trying to do is fairly widespread css3 in newer browsers, and emulated really well (and easily) in IE with the .htc file you can download from there.

As for the markup, I see just 2 elements, with the top one floated right, for example. You'd have to play with z-index to hide excess shadows.
In that site there's also a very similar effect, you should be able to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: good reference. I have used it before some months, but for some reasons I left it. Thanks you remind it!

Answer (score 3):

This should work in all browsers:

```
    .allSidesShadow {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
        -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;

        /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
        /* for IE4 - IE7 */
        filter:
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=1, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=90, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=180, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=270, Color=#C4C4C4);
        -ms-filter: "
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=1, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=90, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=180, Color=#C4C4C4),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=9, Direction=270, Color=#C4C4C4)
        ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by Sekar, needs a little editing,

```
box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10x #C9C9C9;
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
```

this doesnot work on IE(I checked on IE8).

Answer (score 1):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #000;
```

Means 0 pixel left, 0 pixel right, 3px blur, 0 pixel diffuse, use a color slightly darker than the BGs.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your picture now, but for all side shadows I use the below code:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #000;
```

Instead of the 5px use your size.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create several images. One for the left side. One for the right. One for the bottom, etc. And then have several div's and set the background for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with three divs, assuming they are all the same (fixed) width:

```
<div class='top'>
</div>
<div class='middle'>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
</div>

.top{
  background:url('top.png');
  height:20px;
  width:800px;
}
.middle{
  background:url('middle.png') repeat-y;
  width:800px;
  }
.bottom{
  background:url('bottom.png');
  height:20px;
  width:800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make one big image, and use that as the background for the entire content area; then hard-code the positions and sizes of the contained elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the following code in the div in order to drop shadows on all four sides.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```