# How to set a box-shadow to the div element to all sides, left-shadow, right-shadow, top-shadow, bottom-shadow?

Tags: styles, css

I can't create another parent div-container, is it possibly using only css tricks?
box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px black;
will create shadows only from right and bottom borders, but I need left and top too.

Comment: Shadow from all sides? Why can't you simply use border or an image to create this effect? I am not sure if it's possible to combine two shadows on one div.

Comment: 'caz my backgrounds colors are changing dynamicly by animation, and it's not a good job.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467452/css-shadows-all-four-sides-of-div

Comment: Partially transparent background image as a shadow?

Answer (score 14):

With box shadow there are 4 parameters; offset, blur-radius, spread, and color.

This is the code I use on my website. It produces a shadow with 0 offset and blur-radius, 8px spread, and a shade of gray.

```
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #888888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #888888;
```

Here is a quick example of the effect on an image.

[image: Quick example of the effect on an image]

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10x #C9C9C9;
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
```

or

you can use [shadowOn](http://shadowon.codeplex.com/). It's a great jquery plugin and very easy in use.